# Draw restrictive cubic spline diagram of linear regression in r

Tags: r, diagram, non-linear-regression

I am trying to use `ols` in `rms` package to fit the restrictive cubic spline of linear regression. But I don't know how to use `ggplot` to draw the restrictive cubic spline diagram of the regression coefficient? Like the picture:

[image]

And anyone can help me and share the code for me? Thank you very much!

```
library(ggplot2)

library(rms)

set.seed(100)

x1 <- rnorm(30, 100, 20)
x2 <- rnorm(30, 200, 20)
x3 <- rnorm(30, 300, 20)

y <- rnorm(30, 400, 20)

ddist <- datadist(x1,x2,x3)

options(datadist='ddist')

f <- ols(y ~ rcs(x1,3) + x2 + x3 )

anova(f)

ggplot()
```

Comment: `rms` provides a plot method: `plot(Predict(f, x1))` and a  `ggplot` method; `ggplot(Predict(f, x1))`